# Slow down keystrokes in selenium

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am entering text in a textbox in selenium using:

```
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath)).SendKeys("1234");
```

The keystrokes are happening too quick that nothing is happening. Is there a way to slowdown the keystrokes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create your own implementation to simulate the slow typing (human typing)

```
    foreach (char c in value)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        mseconds=random.Next(3, 10) * 100;   
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(mseconds);
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath)).SendKeys(c);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below also to give it sometime to process:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(7));
```

you can increase and decrease

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).